# Does the order matter, if all columns are indexed?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, where-clause

example

```
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = x AND column2 = y
```

Assuming both column1 and column2 are indexed, does the order they appear in the WHERE clause matter?

one of the columns can exclude a higher number of records than the other. Should I put that first, or the column that excludes less records?

Comment: Not in a real DB engine.  Whether SQLite cares, though...?

Comment: Query optimizers are very advanced -- in this case, the order should not matter.  Conditions in joins, sometimes it matters.

Comment: Test both ways with your DB engine and data. Check the execution plan and performance stats. As pointed out already, with most DB engines, the optimizer is smart enough that it shouldn't matter with such a trivial query.

Comment: @thelolcat - you had to point out the flaw in my logic...  I've removed the errant statement from my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No -- boolean expressions with `AND` are [commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property).  The optimizer should be able to figure out which column to use for each component of the index, regardless of what order you write your expression.

Your example is pretty straightforward, but this changes for lots of other cases:

- if you use `OR` instead of `AND`
- if you use `>` or `!=` for range comparison instead of equality comparison
- if you index column1,column2,column3 but only search on column2 and column3
- other cases.

For more information, see my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really).